# Angular table row directive not rendering inside table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to add a row "isrcrow" directive to a table as follows:

```
<table class="table">
        <thead><tr>
                   <th>Artist Name</th>
                   <th>Track Title</th>
                   <th>Version</th>
                   <th>Track Duration</th>
                   <th>Recording Year</th>
                   <th></th>
               </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <isrcrow></isrcrow>
        </tbody>       

    </table>
```

Here is the directive:

```
(function() {
  var isrcorderapp;

  isrcorderapp = angular.module("isrcorderapp", []);

  isrcorderapp.controller("isrcordercontroller", function($scope, $http) {
    return $scope.recordingTypes = [
      {
        type: 'Single'
      }, {
        type: 'Album'
      }, {
        type: 'Live'
      }, {
        type: 'Concert'
      }, {
        type: 'Instrumental'
      }
    ];
  });

  isrcorderapp.directive("isrcrow", function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<tr>\
                <td><input id="artist" ng-model="name"/></td>\
                <td><input id="track"/></td>\
                <td><select id="isrctype" ng-model="isrctype" ng-change="setState(state)" ng-options="s.type for s in recordingTypes" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"></select></td>\
                <td><input id="duration"/></td>\
                <td><input id="year"/></td>\
                <td><input type="button" value="Add ISRC" onclick="AddIsrc()" class="btn btn-small btn-success" />\
                    <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="RemoveIsrc()" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" />\
                </td>\
            </tr>',
      scope: {
        name: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {}
    };
  });

}).call(this);
```

The problem I am experincing is the isrcrow directive doesnt render inside the table body. Its rendered outside and above the table:

Does anyone knows what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: If you are out of options, I recommend making `isrcrow` an attribute, and instead have `<tr isrcrow></tr>` in your HTML, which obviously means modifying your template code to exclude the `<tr>`s.

Comment: This suggestion worked. how can I make this the answer

Comment: I have the same problem. But my thing works in IE, not in Chrome.

Answer (score 30):

Adding a summary of my comments as an answer since it appeared to have helped the OP. :-)

As [GregL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507784/gregl) points out, omitting `replace: true` in a directive with `restrict: 'E'` and `<tr>` as the root template node will result in invalid markup, giving rise to the incorrect rendering of the row.

However, for those using a version of Angular prior to [1.2.13 (romantic-transclusion)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1213-romantic-transclusion-2014-02-14), this solution will not be applicable due to an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459) that has been noted.

A work around would be to instead to use the directive as an attribute (i.e. `restrict: 'A'`) and appropriately modify the template such that `<tr>` is no longer the root template node. This will allow `replace: true` to be used.

Answer (score 7):

I would guess that this is because you have not specified `replace: true` for the `isrcrow` directive. As a result, the final markup would look like:

```
<isrcrow>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        ...
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</isrcrow>
```

Which will be a direct child of a `<tbody>`, which is [invalid markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody). As a result, most modern browsers (e.g. Chrome, and also Firefox, I believe) will try to "fix" your markup to be valid by moving the `<isrcrow>` tag outside of the table.

Instead, if you add `replace: true` to your directive specification, the `<isrcrow>` element won't be rendered, and the browser should see only valid markup and not try to "fix" it.

Comment: For older versions of Angular, there is an issue concerning `replace: true` for directives having a template root of `<tr>`. (cf. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct, but I found them a bit hard to understand/apply, so summarized how I solved it with their help:

The table

```
<tbody>
    <tr isrcrow ng-repeat="..."></tr>
</tbody>
```

The isrcow directive template (without tr, no single root)

```
<td></td>
<td></td>
...
```

The isrcrow directive with

```
restrict: 'A'
replace: false
```

The end results is

```
<tbody>
     <tr isrcrow>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         ...
     </tr>
     <tr isrcrow>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         ...
     </tr>
     ...
</tbody>
```