# Angular is rendering directive outside of table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

We are using Angular 1.3.15
I have an element directive like

```
(function () {
    var controller = function ($scope, $timeout) {
        this.$timeout = $timeout;
        $scope.$watch("vm.spinning", this.throttle.bind(this));
    };

    controller.prototype = {
        throttle: function (spinning, oldValue) {
            if (spinning === oldValue) return;

            this.$timeout.cancel(this.timeout);
            if (spinning) {
                this.timeout = this.$timeout(this.setSpinning.bind(this), 100);
            } else {
                this.setSpinning();
            }
        },
        setSpinning: function() {
            this.spinningThrottled = this.spinning;
        }
    };

    myapp.controller("SpinnerController", ["$scope", "$timeout", controller]);

    myapp.directive("spinner", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                spinning: "=",
            },
            replace: true,
            controller: "SpinnerController",
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true,
            templateUrl: "Views_App/Components/Spinner.html"
        };
    });

    myapp.directive("spinnerGrid", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                spinning: "=",
            },
            replace: true,
            controller: "SpinnerController",
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true,
            templateUrl: "Views_App/Components/SpinnerGrid.html"
        };
    });
})();
```

The spinner grid template

```
<tr data-ng-if="vm.spinningThrottled">
    <td colspan="100">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Please wait...
    </td>
</tr>
```

Usage

```
<table>
   <thead>...</thead>
   <tbody>
      <spinner-grid spinning="searching"></spinner-grid>
      <tr ng-repeat="...">..</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

For somereason the content of the directive is moved outside of the table?

edit: The question might be a duplicate, but K.Toress answer is not since it utilizes EA restriction

Comment: I think its a normal behavior of the `table`, If web page found a table and if it found a `<div>` or any other tag excluding `<tr>` & `<td>` it will remove thats and place it top of the table. Please correct me if i wrong :)

Comment: It works if I place the html code directly in the tbody.

Comment: A similar/the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030080/angular-table-row-directive-not-rendering-inside-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its a normal behavior of the table, if there is a `div` or any other tag (excluding `<tr>`) inside a table without inside of a `<td>` it will remove that and place it on the table.

In your case when html rendering time **(which is before the angular executes its scripts)** html detects there is a unappropriated tag inside the table which is not inside a `td` it will remove and place on top of the table, Then when the angular execution time the directive element is not inside the table instead it will top of the table. that's why its render on top of the table.

Please check you can do something like this,

```
<tbody>
  <tr  data-ng-if="vm.spinningThrottled"><spinner-grid spinning="searching"></spinner-grid></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="...">..</tr>
</tbody>
```

**SpinnerGrid.html**

```
<td colspan="100">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Please wait...
</td>
```

**or check this one**

directive as a attribute of the `<tr>`

```
<tbody>
  <tr spinner-grid spinning="searching"></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="...">..</tr>
</tbody>
```

change the directive definition to support the directive as a attribute. `restrict: "EA"`.

```
myapp.directive("spinnerGrid", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: {
            spinning: "=",
        },
        replace: true,
        controller: "SpinnerController",
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: "Views_App/Components/SpinnerGrid.html"
    };
});
```

Comment: There is no Div in there

Comment: Cant do that because spinningThrottled is part of the directive

Comment: Yes i mean a any html tag other than `<tr>`.

Comment: But replace: true replaces it to the content?

Comment: check the second suggestion.

Comment: yes it will replace, but when the html rendering time (at this time angular not bootstrapped) browser will see invalid markup `<spinner-grid spinning="searching"></spinner-grid>` inside the table and remove it &  place it on the top of the table. after angular bootstrapped, angular will see the directive `<spinner-grid spinning="searching"></spinner-grid>` top of the table, and what it does it replace that one which is in top of the table. that's why you see it on top of the table.

Comment: Yes, buggy browser :D

Comment: :) glad to help you :)