# Table row with custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I want to change the CSS of a table row `<tr>` on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events by creating a custom directive:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="m1">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <custom_tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
      </custom_tr>
      <custom_tr>
        <td>Hi</td>
      </custom_tr>
      <custom_tr>
        <td>Bye</td>
      </custom_tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script>
    var m1 = angular.module("m1", []);

    m1.directive('custom_tr', function()
    {
      var d={};
      d.restrict = 'E';
      d.link = function(scope, element, attr)
      {
        element.bind('mouseenter', function(){
          element.css({'font-style': 'italic'});
        });
        element.bind('mouseleave', function(){
          element.css({'font-style': 'normal'});
        });
      }
      return d;
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Can anyone please explain the reason why its not working with a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `<custom-tr>` tag is not a valid element inside tables. As you can see in your element inspector, the browser will replace the tags for valid `<tr>` tags instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030080/angular-table-row-directive-not-rendering-inside-table) for more information.

What you can do is make your custom-tr an `attribute`. The browser will then render it as a valid TR, but use your custom directive as an attribute to replace the styling.

See the following code for reference:

```
// Make sure you define the directive correctly, (note the customTr vs custom-tr)
m1.directive('customTr', function()......

// Use your directive as an attribute
d.restrict = 'A';
```

And for the HTML, use the newly defined attribute with valid tr-tags.

```
<table>
  <tr custom-tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr custom-tr>
    <td>Hi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr custom-tr>
    <td>Bye</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome! Happy coding :)

Comment: By the way, is there any way to save the element's CSS in some object, so that I can return the CSS to the original state on the `mouseleave` event?

Comment: The style of elements is stored in the element itself. You can simply access it through `element.style.xxxxx`.

Comment: I tried that using `element.style.color`, but am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined`.

Comment: There are several reasons this could be caused. I suggest you open up a new question which explains the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a template for your directive and put `<tr>` and `<td>` tag into. also you can define a scope to pass `td` content to directive. like this.

```js
var m1 = angular.module("m1", []);
m1.directive('customTr', function()
    {
      var d={};
      d.restrict = 'E';
      d.scope = { content:"@"}
      d.link = function(scope, element, attr)
      {
        element.bind('mouseenter', function(){
          element.css({'font-style': 'italic'});
        });
        element.bind('mouseleave', function(){
          element.css({'font-style': 'normal'});
        });
      }
      d.template = '<tr ><td>{{content}}</td></tr>';
      return d;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-app="m1">
    <table>
      <custom-tr content="Hello"></custom-tr>
      
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't want to provide the inner html of the `<custom-tr>` as a `content` attribute as you have shown. I just want to replace `<tr>` with a custom element which behaves just like normal `<tr>`, but having a difference in the CSS on mouse events.